# Does the encoding parameter work for pandas.read_excel?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to read .xls files by using pandas.read_excel. They are adsorption data directly exported from the software of the measurement equipment..I tried

```
pd.read_excel(r'./002-197.XLS',sheet_name=0, index_col=None,encoding='ISO-8859-1', na_values=['NA'])
```

But it shows:

> *** No CODEPAGE record, no encoding_override: will use 'ascii' Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "D:\PPy\data analysis\file_to_rdirectory.py", line 17, in
>   
>       exp_info=pd.read_excel(r'./002-197.XLS',sheet_name=0, index_col=None,encoding='ISO-8859-1', na_values=['NA'])
>
> File
>   "D:\Anaconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_base.py",
>   line 304, in read_excel
>       io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
>
> File
>   "D:\Anaconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_base.py",
>   line 824, in **init**
>       self._reader = self._enginesengine
>
> File
>   "D:\Anaconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_xlrd.py",
>   line 21, in **init**
>       super().**init**(filepath_or_buffer)
>
> File
>   "D:\Anaconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_base.py",
>   line 353, in **init**
>       self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
>
> File
>   "D:\Anaconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_xlrd.py",
>   line 36, in load_workbook
>       return open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\xlrd__init__.py",
>   line 148, in open_workbook
>       bk = book.open_workbook_xls(
>
> File "D:\Anaconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line
>   108, in open_workbook_xls
>       bk.fake_globals_get_sheet()
>
> File "D:\Anaconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line
>   732, in fake_globals_get_sheet
>       self.get_sheets()
>
> File "D:\Anaconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line
>   723, in get_sheets
>       self.get_sheet(sheetno)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line
>   714, in get_sheet
>       sh.read(self)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\sheet.py", line
>   1369, in read
>       strg = unpack_string(data, 7, bk.encoding or bk.derive_encoding(), lenlen=1)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\biffh.py", line
>   250, in unpack_string
>       return unicode(data[pos:pos+nchars], encoding)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\timemachine.py",
>   line 31, in 
>       unicode = lambda b, enc: b.decode(enc)
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position
>   10: ordinal not in range(128)

I tried to copy all the data from this excel file to a newly created excel file and it worked well. And I noticed that the first line in the error report.

```
*** No CODEPAGE record, no encoding_override: will use 'ascii' Traceback (most recent call last):
```

it seems the file doesn't have codepage record and can't be encoded by 'ascii'. So I tried to provide it by using encoding='' and encoding_override='' to the syntax, but no improvement. Can anyone help me?

Comment: df= pd.read_csv('Your.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1')  try changing with  df= pd.read_csv('Your.csv', encoding='latin1')

Comment: Thank you. But I need to read excel not .csv.

Answer (score 4):

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path, encoding_override='CORRECT_ENCODING')
df = pd.read_excel(wb)
```

Comment: This one throws an error `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Book` .

Comment: It worked okay for me. [`pd.read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) works fine with `xlrd.Book` as it is commented in the official documentation